# regex 4-6 digits ending with 00, but lowest value is 5000

Tags: regex

i'm trying to make a regex for this condition:

- 6 numbers max
- finish always with `00`
- lowest input `5000`

These should match:

```
5000
11100
699900
999900
```

These should not match:

```
900
4900
12345
999999
1230000
```

I browsed through the site, but without success.
I'm not very good at regex - could somebody please help?

Comment: the only number possible is **5000000** as you have the conditon 6 numbers max only finish always with 00 and start mandatory with 5000

Comment: So, between 4 and 6 *digits*, ending with 00, and no lower than 5000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following

```
^([5-9]\d|[1-9]\d{2,3})00$
```

Comment: This doesn't match 11100

Comment: @HansKesting Yes, you're right. Fixed using regex from my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean 5000 *or above*:

```
^([5-9]\d|[1-9]\d{2,3})00$
```

See a [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/HFwworcJpr).

Comment: I am not sure if this is correct. Are you clear with the question?

Comment: Yes thats what I have asked in the comment! I am not sure why to use a regex if the only possible number for OP is 5000000?

Comment: @user3414693 I think I've got it now - look at the sequence: it's any number between 5000 and 999900. Not *all* input must have 6 digits - that's just the nax

Comment: I am sorry but I think you got it wrong. Read again:- `6 numbers max only, finish always with 00 and start mandatory with 5000` 5001 is not 6 digits and it does not start with 5000

Comment: Since you are the moderator I respectfully suggest you to close this question as unclear what OP is asking. Instead of playing a guess game! (Kinldy forgive me if I asked for a trouble by not upvoting a moderators answer!)

Comment: @user3414693 I will forgive you *on this occasion*. Make sure it doesn't happen again ;) The question is clear enough to answer. I'll edit it to make it cleaerer

Comment: I like your answer. But it will accept 00000 as valid one. You may change to `^([5-9]\d|[1-9]\d{2,3})00$`

Comment: @Bohemian:- Yes even I like this answer. But the OP's original question was very difficult to understand!

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov yes I realised that too (and came up with the same fix)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Interesting. I thought that `<kdb>` made links look like buttons, which I thought looked good. FYI I've gone back over my posts and cleaned them *all* out.

Comment: @Bohemian:- Good work Sir. Actually I am new to this site. So got it wrong. But your answer was always correct. It was that I was not able to relate it to the question asked. So asked this [meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226935/what-to-do-when-moderators-are-guessing-the-answer-instead-of-closing-it) to understand more. +1 for the answer and +1 to the question edit!

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should match all of them. We deal with the 4 digit case separately:

```
^([1-9][0-9]{2,3}00)|([5-9][0-9]00)$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^([5-9]\d{1,3}|[1-4]\d{2,3})00$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^[5-9][0-9]{1,3}00
```

So has to start with a digit between 5 and 9 ^[5-9]
Then can have any number between 0-9 1, 2 or 3 times and must end with 00

Look at the following [demo](http://regex101.com/r/bH9aF2)